# Dynamically change the class of a div nested in a gridview item template from code behind c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview, itemtemplate

I need to change the class of a div nested inside a gridview item template, i have given the runat="server" tag and an id for the div. How can we change the class of that particular div upon gridview databind based on each row conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### ASPX

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="gv_OnRowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div id="yourDiv" runat="server"></div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

### Code-behind

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
        HtmlGenericControl div = (HtmlGenericControl)e.Row.FindControl("yourDiv");
        div.Attributes.Add("class", "ClassYouWantToAdd");
    }
}
```